# Iterate over table of tables

Tags: lua

I have this table `local cookies = {{["name"]=23, ["value"]=333}, {["name"]=222, ["value"]=33233}}` and I want to iterate over the subtables to find the one with the correct "name". Here is what I have tried

```
  for _,elm in ipairs(cookies) do
    for k,v in ipairs(elm) do
      print(k)
      if k == "name" and v == 222 then
          print(v)
      end
    end
  end
```

I does show in the outer for loop that it sees to tables, however, it does not even enter the inner for loop - why? How can I find the subtable for which "name" equals a certain value?

Comment: Try `pairs` instead of inner `ipairs`

Comment: The "i" in `ipairs` stands for _integer_, or more specifically, positive integer keys up to but not including the first "missing" one (`cookies[k] == nil`).

Answer (score 3):

`ipairs` only iterates over the keys 1, 2, 3, ..., so it won't visit the key `"name"`. If you want to visit all keys, use `pairs` (though be warned the order of iteration is not predictable).

However, for your example you don't need an inner loop at all. You can simple get the name of elm as `elm.name`:

```
for _,elm in ipairs(cookies) do
    if elm.name == "222" then
        print(elm.name, elm.value)
    end
end
```

In fact, if you don't need the ordering or need to support duplicated cookie names, your `cookies` table could become a dictionary of name => value, allowing you to write this with no loops:

```
print(cookies["222"]) --> 33233
```

Comment: Even duplicated cookies can be done as a dict of `name => [values]`, though that still loses ordering.